# React createContext argument required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reducers

I am going to use reacts context api plus reducers. Because I found many ways to implement this and a lack of documentation I don't know if I am doing right.
I order to have a global state I have done this:

```
import {createContext, useReducer} from "react";
import {appReducer} from "../reducers/appReducer";


function lazyInitializer() {
    return {db: 1}
}

export const AppContext = createContext(); //Invalid number of arguments, expected 1 (defaultValue)

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [globalState, appDispatch] = useReducer(appReducer, null, lazyInitializer);
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={{globalState, appDispatch}}>
            {props.children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}
export default AppContextProvider;
```

Do I have to supply `createContext` a default value? Is this the right way to use lazy initializes? It does work how it is above. If there is a better solution realizing a global state please tell me.
Btw I dont wanna use Redux in order to keep the project simple.

Comment: The error clearly says it needs a default value. I don't understand why you're asking this this question. Do you have a reason to not pass a default value?

Comment: I am trying to understand why this works without passing anything. And which default value? The same I already gave a to the useReducer function? And in some tutorials they leave it empty...it seems that it was changed by react recently.

Comment: "The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree. This default value can be helpful for testing components in isolation without wrapping them" - whatever you want to pass to the components to make them work in isolation I guess

Comment: Just add `{}` into default value and you will no longer have the error